# method for printing entire database column

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, jdbc

I have a working database application that simply spits out the entire "Name" column

```
String sql = "SELECT Name FROM my_list;";   
ResultSet infoDump = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
String actID = null;
while (infoDump.next()){
    actID = infoDump.getString("Name");
    System.out.println(actID);
}
```

I want to be able to wrap this up in a nice little function like so

```
printTheNames(sqlQuery)
{
    ResultSet infoDump = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
    String actID = null;
    while (infoDump.next()){
        actID = infoDump.getString("Name");
        System.out.println(actID);
    }
}
printTheNames("SELECT Name FROM my_list;");
```

I'm not sure what syntax to use because when I do anything close to this it gives me all kinds of errors. I'm sure it's very simple but would there be anywhere I could find a quick example?

Comment: Appear to be missing parts of the function declaration. Add `public void` to `printTheNames(sqlQuery)` and it should work fine.

Comment: Just use a ArrayList.  Populate it in the function and return it.

Comment: If you get errors, then you should include those errors in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method signature is wrong, should be

```
public void printTheNames(String sqlQuery)
{
    ResultSet infoDump = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
    String actID = null;
    while (infoDump.next()){
        actID = infoDump.getString("Name");
        System.out.println(actID);
    }
}
```

And call as you are doing now.

```
printTheNames("SELECT Name FROM my_list;");
```

Assuming you are calling the function in same class, otherwise you need a  an instance to invoke the method.

Comment: A concern here is the method expects the sqlQuery parameter to have the database field Name embedded in it. I would suggest passing in a second String, call it field, and use that in the getString call.

Comment: @Krazick Yes true, but OP is basically facing an issue with syntax. Adding additional parameters quite easy to make the method generic.